# Split Dates from String in C#

Tags: c#, date, split

I have a String like this:

```
19.11.2022 /20.11.2022 + 17.12.2022 /18.12.2022 + 14.01.2023 /15.01.2023 + 11.02.2023 /12.02.2023 + 12.03.2023 + 23.04.2023
```

OR THIS

```
15.01.2023 (13:30 - 15:00 Uhr)
```

OR THIS

```
04.03.2023 + 05.03.2023
```

Or any more.

Now i want to split the dates and write to xml. But how i can Split them in C#?

I Tried nothing at the Moment because I have no idea.

Comment: First search for slash `/` and use method _one_ if found. If not, search for `(` and use method _two_ if found. If not, use method _three_. Each method would be simple to program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[String.Split](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=net-7.0) and [DateTime.Parse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parse?view=net-7.0) are likely a good place to start.